# Update progress bar via ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```html
<?php


echo '<style> #myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
} </style>';


echo '<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">1%</div>
</div>';



  echo'<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>';

  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
 function move() {
  $.getJSON("convo.php",function(data){});
  
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");  
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    $.getJSON("progress.php",function(results){
    width=results;
    if (width > 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
    else if(width==100)
    {
      elem.style.width = width + "%"; 
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + "%";
    } 
    else 
    {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + "%"; 
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1  + "%";
    }
    });
  }
 
}

</script>';
 ob_flush(); 
    flush(); 



echo '<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>'
?>

/**** progress.php ***/

<?php

 $content = @file_get_contents('logs/123.txt');

 if($content){
  
    exit(json_encode($progress));
}


/**** convo.php ***/

will generate logs/123.txt file
```

Can i know is there anyway for me to read a txt file & update my progress bar via ajax while the other function is running and updating this txt file?

But the progress bar should be updated real time , without waiting txt file update process finishes.

I already tried doing this but the issue is codeigniter keeps on running first process  (.txt file update process) even though I call the 2nd function  (updateProgressBar) using ajax while the 1st process is running it keeps on loading without returning data until finishes the 1st process. but when the 1st process is finished it returns the data which is useless .

can i know why codeigniter won't allow me to run 2 functions simultaneously?

Thanks in advance

Comment: share your code of ajax and html and what did you try so far?

Comment: this has nothing to do with codeigniter really and all to do with requests and php. the two functions operate in different instances and therefore do not communicate with one another. if you want a progress bar you can't do it this way.

Comment: @Alex.  Thanks for your reply.  But I have tried this with php and ajax.  it works.  But when I try to do it with codeigniter this issue did come up. any possible way that you suggest?

Comment: i'm sorry but that just doesn't make any sense. `getJSON()` or any similar method, won't enter the internal function until it has completed (unless you flush the output to the browser). you can test this functionality with a simple `console.log()` and a request that goes to a sleep command. so by saying that you've done this before and it worked I am frankly dubious.

Comment: @Alex, Yes it works. i have changed the above code . have a look . it works on normal php but when i add it to controllers and use it on codeginiter it doesn't work. i mean it works but it doesn't update the progress live .it will update the progress bar at once.

Comment: well now your js code is completely different for 1 you don't have a nested ajax as you did before. hence why it "works". i put quotes around that because, as you pointed out, it only updates at once so I fail to see the point of this at all esp since I doubt your log file is readable as an integer only as is required for your width statements. i'd just add an ajax spinner. in any case, if you want to adapt this code to codeigniter, simply put the contents of `progress` in a controller function and the contents of `convo` in a controller function, keep your js/html, and just change the urls.

Comment: Plus you have provided no code related to Codeigniter, so we have no idea on how you are attempting to use the code you have shown in Codeigniter. Would I be correct in saying you are very new to CodeIgniter.  Controller filename names, view filennames etc...